# How can I give specific IP and port that my code requires

Tags: python, django

In django I am using python osc, using osc server which required IP address and Port no. to run.

When I run that specific file on terminal I add the ip and port like:

```
OSC.py --ip --port
```

Now I want to implement this in django but don't know where to add ip and port

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `python manage.py runserver` command then you can pass the ip and port number as well.
**Ex-1:**  `python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.100:5001`
**Ex-2:**  `python manage.py runserver 5001` # only port overriding
**Ex-3:**  `python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.100` # ip only

Comment: Thanks, But I am using pythonosc, osc-server. I have a device which sends information and the script reads the information. The script wants an IP and port which it connects to. When I run that particular script in terminal I mention the IP and port as stated above, How can I do this in django?